# Remove Solution: Trial Base Solution & Project Field Service

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

How can I remove the solution: **Free Base Trial Solution** from my trial online CRM 2016? I also have another solution called : **Project Field Service** which I am unable to remove.

I also removed my sample data, but I can still see lots of Contacts created by Owner: System. How can I remove this as well? Are these related to the solutions I want to delete? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I havent shown an example of my own. However, people who know the answer would know what Im talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to settings -> solutions and delete the solutions from CRM. If they are managed, it will remove all the customizations.

To delete data, I always delete all accounts. That deletes alle related records as well (Cases, contacts, opportunities etc.) Depending on your needs, you might need to delete unrelated data as well.
As far as I know, there's no single 'delete all' button.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it by resetting my instance, starting from scratch and selecting NO entities  (Sales, Marketing, Field Service).